# Can we set android navigation drawer menu based on user level?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm creating an apps which using Navigation Drawer Activity. My login activity will take the user to main activity after logged in, which contained the navigation drawer.

I'dl like to set up the navigation drawer menu based on the user role which returned by the JSON, e.g, role=1 will take you to navigation menu for role-1, role=2 will show you navigation menu for role-2

I tried to set onCreate with if(role) condition but it gave me error as the following

"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener)"

This is what i tried

```
 if(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(role))==1){

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            namaUser = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.NamaUser);
            emailUser = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.EmailUser);
            emailUser.setText(emailHolder);
            namaUser.setText(namaDepan +" "+namaBelakang);

            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

        }else{


                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
                View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
                namaUser = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.NamaUser);
                emailUser = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.EmailUser);
                emailUser.setText(emailHolder);
                namaUser.setText(namaDepan +" "+namaBelakang);

                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                });
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();
        }
```

it gave me

"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener)"

any solution?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is your class extend to `Fragment`?

Comment: hi @JohnJoe, what to do in order to know that?
this is how the class looks like

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{}

Comment: can you post a minimal example of` MainActivity` and full exception?